# p5.js script failing with empty variable?

Tags: javascript, class, global-variables, undefined, p5.js

I am so close to completing a script that I have been battling now for 2 months. (p5.js graphic)
Here is my problem:

- I have a variable that is supposed to be updated based on a dropdown selection.
- When I give the variable a set value, the script works.
- when I leave it empty to be updated by the dropdown selector listening function. the script runs but with an undefined variable.
- At some point I am loosing the value that was set by the updater function and I can't seem to find out where and how. Any pointers please?

Here is the link to the build:
https://editor.p5js.org/ekspresyon/sketches/iTnv38kyA

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting project, I like particle/molecule simulations. 
The most obvious question first; Why don't you just set the variable to an initial value?

This seems to be a logic issue. The path/flow in your code could be better.

When you don't set the 'f' variable it is 'undefined'. In setup you add the water and air molecules. But in the constructor of the molecule class there is this:

```
this.f = f;
this.speed_x = random(-f,f);
this.speed_y = random(-f,f);
```

What would random(-undefined, undefined) be? That number does not exist.

With the current code you can only add molecules when the global 'f' variable is set, which seems like a bad practise. You can either add molecules after setting the 'f' variable, use an initial value or update those values in the molecule after changing the 'f' variable.

Also, the changes to the 'f' variable are never passed to the existing molecules, you only change the global 'f' variable.

Another thing; It's not necessary to check the speed every frame. Only when the value in the dropbox changes. Instead of calling speed in the draw function, add this to the setup function:

```
var temp = document.getElementById("molshake");
temp.addEventListener('change', speed);
```

This adds a listener to the event 'onchange' and when the dropbox is changes, it calls speed();